# What's the significance of the boy with the drum?

Tags: trope, triangle

Near the end of Triangle, at the car accident scene, we briefly see a boy that appears to belong to the parade they were having:

[image: Parade]

This boy is sitting on the floor (crying?) with his drum in front of him:

[image: Boy with drum]

The **AO** that can be seen on the drums (see red cicle in fist image) are the same as on the **A**e**O**lus:

[image: Band instruments on Aeolus]

They were hard to spot, but I'm having trouble interpreting the connection between these. Would this be another hint that she constructed her after-life experience (what you could call "hell") from elements that she saw just before dying? The post-it in the kitchen reminded her of the boat-trip, the seagull she overrun is seen time and time again on the Triangle as well as on the Aeolus (often feasting on her "friends") and finally the AO parade, which may relate to Aeolus (you don't speak the "e"). Does that make sense? Is there a better explanation?

---

Bonus question: What could the actual meaning of AO be? Is there a popular parade with these initials in reality?

Comment: Good question. Also good observation!

Comment: @KevinHowell: Thanks. I tried to google the appropriate shots, but didn't find any, so I had to fire up the video, anyway.

Comment: It could be a reference to Alpha and Omega http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_and_Omega

Comment: @Foole: Yes, I thought about that as well (after writing the question). "Beginning and End" could mean the car crash is both the beginning and end. But why is it seen on the Aeolis, too? I would expect a stronger significance, other than just popping it in another time.